# Insert UL items into alphabetical list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list that is generated dynamically and is automatically ordered alphabetically. However, I would like the list to contain every letter (A–Z), but for the items which get added with jQuery not to be links.

```
<ul class="letters-listing">
<li><a href="#">a</a></li>
<li><a href="#">b</a></li>
<li><a href="#">c</a></li>
<li><a href="#">d</a></li>
<li><a href="#">e</a></li>
<li><a href="#">f</a></li>
<li><a href="#">g</a></li>
<li><a href="#">h</a></li>
<li><a href="#">j</a></li>
<li><a href="#">k</a></li>
<li><a href="#">l</a></li>
<li><a href="#">m</a></li>
<li><a href="#">n</a></li>
<li><a href="#">o</a></li>
<li><a href="#">p</a></li>
<li><a href="#">r</a></li>
<li><a href="#">s</a></li>
<li><a href="#">t</a></li>
<li><a href="#">v</a></li>
<li><a href="#">w</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, for example, no letter "i" is output as a list item, so I would like to insert `<li>i</li>` in the relevant place in the list so I have a full A–Z listing.

Would I use an if statement and append for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you start with a fully populated a-z list without the links... and then add links when there's a match?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, as the list is generated with PHP by a tag system, so I think adding the list items with jQuery is going to be easier. Any ideas?

Comment: It's an interesting issue... I think you'll need a couple things going: 1) To get the innerHtml of the onload-generated list, and to store those values in an array. 2) You'll need to validate the array for alphabetic consistency. 3) If there's a gap, generate and insert a list item containing the missing letter as innerHtml into the document ul (at correct position)... and potentially populate the array with that same value (also at the correct position), and then move onto the next letter.

Comment: Thanks – seems like it's out of my abilities judging by what you're suggesting! I'll keep looking into it. I'd love it if you could point me in the right direction with what to Google for?